# Page scrolling is not smooth in firefox

Tags: firefox, asp-classic, scroll

When I use Firefox I have noticed when I'm using my mouse to scroll the page I'm on the page tends to stick or not move for a moment. I just tried IE and no problem there. I was even on the same page and Firefox still tends to hang up. Anyone can help me out?

Note that the website is mad with classic asp.

I found a similar post here but not any specific solution.
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=324499

Comment: My FF version is 28.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, did some experimenting and found a setting in about:config that makes Smooth Scrolling both smooth and fast: look in **about:config** for `mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount`. By default that has a value of **5**. I changed that into **50** and now the Smooth Scrolling looks and feels like before.

But I need a way to do it programmatic. I mean if the website detect that the browser is FF then it will do the above manual things programmatic.

an alternate and more efficient solution is this:

[How to programatically change the about:config dom.max_script_run_time value in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703594/how-to-programatically-change-the-aboutconfig-dom-max-script-run-time-value-in)