# How to access the Firefox preferences hash table?

Tags: firefox

Does anyone know how I could access the Firefox preferences hash table when it is running? I want to see what preferences exist in the hash table.

Comment: You mean programatically, or via firefox UI ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible through firefox UI. It probably should be somehow programatically.

Comment: What kind of preferences? [These](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tab-preferences-and-settings)?

Comment: About:config preferences. Those are just a subset of available preferences.

Comment: I believe it's not possible. I hope it's not possible. If it's possible I'm moving to chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible to programmatically (via web) access `about:config` preferences. I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14704494/1598508), where Wesley tells the same. I couldn't yet find it in documentation that it's not possible, but I'm sure it is. If it is possible - it's a bug. A critical one.

If a browser allowed this - it would be a huge security leak. Such configs might contain vulnerable data, possibly private or even embarrasing. For example `browser.newtabpage.blocked` pref contains blocked `about:newtab` sites, a trace of user's history.

It is however possible to access preferences when driving firefox by an external software, that interacts with firefox UI. It is then perfectly OK, because a user has to initiate such an action.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I don't really want to change anything there, so read-only access would be sufficient something like printing out the hash table by instrumenting the source code,... Do you know any external software I could read the hash table via that?

Comment: You don't get it. Read only access is a leak already. If I could in my javascript access preferences, then I could process it in some fancy way and post it to my server to illegally gather sensitive data. If your browser allowed my script to access list of extensions, preferences of addons and plugins, fragments of history - would you use such a browser?