# How to wait long enough for Django views results on Firefox?

Tags: django, google-chrome, firefox

I'm developing a website with Django 2.2, using :

- Centos 7
- Mozilla Firefox 60.6.0
- Google Chrome 73.0.3683.86
- Docker and Docker compose

The first page allows the user to submit data from a formatted file (equivalent to csv) and the second page shows the result of calculations (done row by row) in a datatable. 
I have noticed a difference between Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome:
For big files, on Chrome, the web browser waits long enough to receive and display the results of calculations. Whereas in Firefox, the web browser stops waiting for localhost and the "results" page is not loaded.

As the problem occured when the file exceeded a certain size, I have guessed that the app spent too much calculating time and Firefox stopped waiting for the response before to load the "results" page. 
So I changed my view to accelerate calculations. The problem still persists with big files. With files from approximately 3.5Mo the results page os displayed or not (almost randomly).

I tried to raise "dom.max_script_run_time" in my [Mozilla settings](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/make-firefox-wait-longer-time-out-41249.html) but this [can't be done programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703594/how-to-programatically-change-the-aboutconfig-dom-max-script-run-time-value-in).

I saw that [Celery can be used for long time running calculations](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-celery-with-django-for-background-task-processing--cms-28732), but in my case, calculations can be performed on 1 or 3000 rows. I would like to find a solution without using Celery.

Another solution could be to use JavaScript to set a timeout when Firefox is detected as web browser, the to add a error message, I also would like to avoid this.

I expect my app to work well at least on Mozilla Firefox, Safari, Opera and Google Chrome Web browsers. 
Thanks for your help !

Comment: You might need to do this asynchronously using javascript. Where you would make a request through an api exposed by your django application. Then the server will send html very quick and will not hang and the javascript will make the call which will wait for a response from your server. This will not render block the page and make the browser unresponsive. You cannot change the timeout of a users Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am trying to load data after having loaded the second page. What you are explaining seems to be possible with the datatables. If not, I'll fix it with JS.